# Can't ssh? Probably an issue with bash_profile on my Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, ssh, bash

So, I am a beginner with all of this stuff, attempting to learn Selenium Webdriver using Java/Maven on my Mac.  I followed the instructions [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) to set up my bash_profile.  This is what I have (I also have Python installed) -

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# Maven configuration
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1i
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
# Java configuration
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

I get valid responses if I do `java -version` and `mvn --version`, but when I try to ssh, I get `command not found`.  If I comment out all of the Maven/Java stuff in bash_profile, I can ssh, so I know somehow this is problem.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

should be

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

in your bash_rc, the first time you export your $PATH, you did it correctly but not the second time,

```
export PATH=$M2:$PATH
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

after the second export, PATH contains only the java/bin directory, so I don't understand how you could do a mvn --version

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

you need to write

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The version you have now erases all of the path and replaces it with `$JAVA_HOME/bin`; instead, you want to *add* `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to the front (or the back) of the existing path.